# Battery Saver Mode on Nokia Lumia 1320

Tags: lumia, battery-saver

How do I turn on battery saver mode on my Nokia Lumia phone? Its battery goes low very quickly and I am sick and tired of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to turn on battery saver mode on your Nokia Lumia, go through the following steps:

1. Go to Settings.
2. Select battery saver.
3. Turn it ON.

But keep in mind that after turning it on you won't be able to receive WhatsApp, email and other notifications.